# what difficulty would be there if WSDL hadn't existed?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have searched for use of WSDL, but I am not able to fully comprehend what would happen if WSDL hadn't existed.
A example explaining the scenario would be nice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

THe WSDL is the "contract" which describe the objet use to call or response a WS and the service and operation expose.
In SOAP architecture, if you don't have this you d'ont know how to dialogue with the WS.

Additionnaly, in many language, it used to generate class that represent the objet.
there is plugin for maven or graddle for example.

Comment: I understand that it is contract, but like rest services we don't require WSDL then why do we need WSDL in SOAP.

Comment: Suppose I create a endpoint and send soap message on it. Where does WSDL come into picture?